# Selecting drop-down using Selenium Python - Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id=

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

Trying to automate filling out the search form on http://ibew.org/Tools/Construction-Jobs-Board

The code I have written so far aims to select the drop-down menu for 'Classification' and select the 'Inside Journeyman Wireman' value.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

b = webdriver.Chrome()
b.maximize_window() #For maximizing window
b.implicitly_wait(100) #gives an implicit wait for 100 seconds

b.get("http://ibew.org/Tools/Construction-Jobs-Board")

b.find_element_by_id("TabContainerSearch_SearchTab_ddlClass").click() 
selectclass = Select(b.find_element_by_id('TabContainerSearch_SearchTab_ddlClass'))
selectclass.select_by_visible_text('Inside Journeyman Wireman')
```

The error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="TabContainerSearch_SearchTab_ddlClass"]"}
```

What is my sin? :P
I am day into Selenium and a few days into Python. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: given link is not working

Comment: Please update correct link ,Link is not working.

Comment: Are you sure that's the ID `TabContainerSearch_SearchTab_ddlClass` ? They have two spans with a similiar name, but don't see the `_ddlClass`

Comment: Sorry, Navneet and Justin. Not sure why the link didn't work for you. @abestrad thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catch is the element you are trying to identify is inside an `iframe` tag - you will see it in the DOM if you scroll further up. You need to first switch context to that `iframe` before working with any of its child elements.

Use either of these options after the `b.get` line.

```
iframe=b.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[src='http://ibew.org/jobsboard/']")
b.switch_to.frame(iframe)
selectclass = Select(b.find_element_by_id('TabContainerSearch_SearchTab_ddlClass'))
selectclass.select_by_visible_text('Inside Journeyman Wireman')
```

Or

```
WebDriverWait(b, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src='http://ibew.org/jobsboard/']")))
selectclass = Select(b.find_element_by_id('TabContainerSearch_SearchTab_ddlClass'))
selectclass.select_by_visible_text('Inside Journeyman Wireman')
```

Consider using `WebDriverWait` wherever possible. Implicit wait of 100 seconds defeats the point of automation! These imports are required for `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thanks @0buz. The code worked like a charm. +1 on using WebDriverWait instead of implicit wait. I had put 100s to try and make the code work. :D